# Django. Изменение статуса аккаунта( типо покупка подписки и ограничение бесплатной подписки)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Подскажите, где я могу почитать более свежую инфу про ограничения для пользователей, покупку подписки и все в таком духе. Как мне ограничить доступ к чему-то. Например бесплатный пользователь может создать только 10 постов, а премиум пользователь уже сколько захочет. Подскажите пожалуйста где найти инфу по этому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во view можно делать проверки пользователей. К примеру через `request.user` - он хранит данные о текущем пользователе. Можно расширить модель **User** и добавить поле, к примеру поле **premium**(типа **bool** - *True* или *False*). Соответственно у премиум пользователей оно будет True. Ну и во view делать проверку (то есть если у текущего пользователя `premium=True`, то отобразить ему определенную страницу, если нет, то вернуть что-то другое). Для ограничения доступа к страницам можно использовать декораторы или миксины (в зависимости какой у вас view, функция или класс).Так же можно использовать группы .Можно проверять права пользователя через функции has_perm, has_perms, with_perm ит.д Подробнее можете почитать тут: https://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/auth/default.html#topic-authorization

P.S Не пугайтесь, что 1.7. Инфа там тоже подойдет. Ну или можете поискать ту же информацию в более свежой документации

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую, почитаю

Answer (score 0):

Создайте [группы](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#groups) для каждого уровня доступа

В зависимости от [прав](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) (в т.ч. и [созданных вами](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions)) разрешаете/запрещаете функционал/контент.

Группы и права назначаются пользователям. Почитайте больше на эту тему в официальной документации, разделы о пользователях и правах доступа, ссылки на последнее прикреплены

Comment: Спасибо большое.